# C# Selenium Chrome Add URLs to Insecure Content

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to add a site URL to the list of allowable sites for insecure content.  I cannot for the life of me find anything on the subject.  I was able to do something similar for adding a URL list to allow flash but can't get the Chrome specific settings syntax to work for the insecure content tab.  This is the code I used to get the URL list to the allowable flash settings:

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(seleniumLocation);
var options = new ChromeOptions();
List<string> flashUrls = new List<string>() { 
       "https://www.someplace.com","https://www.someotherplace.com" };
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_plugins_allowed_for_urls", flashUrls);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

That works perfectly fine.  I've tried different variations of this for Insecure Content but none are able to add the URL.

```
List<string> insecureUrls = new List<string>() { 
     "https://www.someplace.com","https://www.someotherplace.com" };
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.insecure_content_allowed_for_urls", insecureUrls);
```

I'm pretty certain what's wrong is the profile.insecure_content_allowed_for_urls portion but can't find any info anywhere about what it should actually be.  Below is a screenshot of the setting in Chrome.

[image: chrome insecure content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer for anyone that finds this later.  managed_insecure_content_allowed_for_urls was the correct syntax.

```
List<string> insecureUrls = new List<string>() {  "https://www.someplace.com" };
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_insecure_content_allowed_for_urls", insecureUrls);
```